# How can I assign a public IP address to each of my devices?

Tags: networking, ip, router, subnet

My ISP (plusnet) has given me a block of 8 IP addresses I can use, so each of my devices can have a different public IP address.

Unfortunately, they don't offer support on how to do this, I've tried to gather information and so far I've realised I can only use 5 of them, 1 is used as a gateway address for the router and the first and last for other reasons.

From what else I've gathered, I need to assign each device the an IP address, then match it within the router so they're linked and it understands to use that IP address publically for that device, but I tried to do that with one of my devices, manually configuring the IP, then I changed the routers gateway IP to that of one of the 8 IP's I have, yeah, I think I have no clue what I'm doing and I cant learn IP addresses and subnetting and whatever else within the next day or so?

I think I will need to buy a new router as this one provided by plusnet does not do the job.

I'm desperate to get this to work, needed for my business but I have no help and little experience other than studying IT in college (in the UK so age 16/17 - my friend gave me the exam answers - 9 years later, I realise I should have paid attention haha!)

thank you if you can help with advice or anything!

Dale.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two main ways this can be done, the choice of which is largely made by your ISP.

1. The set of ip's your isp has given you (typically a .. subnet) can be routed through another IP. This configuration mostly applies to business where I'm from. In that case the router has an internet-facing public ip, and a seperate also public "lan"-facing (typical terminology is DMZ) ip within your subnet. They can be very similar or very different. Your devices will have a public ip (with the right subnet) and the local public ip of the router as the default gateway.
2. The set of ip's your isp has given you is terminated at the endpoint device (modem, router, gateway or whatever they call it). So no IP routing happens on your router (ignore the terminology here). There will be a function in the router to bridge the public ip's from your devices on the lan towards the outside. The terminology depends on the router vendor.

2 bis) In a lot of setups, you can make this work with a switch (or switch-like) hooked up to the last device of the ISP, before your router. The devices get a public ip directly from the ISP (sometimes even with DHCP, but that's never a long term solution). There is no router involved (for those public ip's, you can obviously still hook one up to provide simple clients with internet)

Footnote: **beware** you are facing the public internet. There is a lot of malicious traffic going around. You will need to absolutely keep the machines firewalled and services up to date, and even then you would be wise to limit the access. And *plan* to have the machines compromised.

Footnote: I don't want to advertise my services here, but if you are truly in urgent need...

Comment: Hey Joris, I'd love some support in setting up if possible! Don't seem to be able to private message on here, perhaps I can leave my skype then delete it after you have seen it? skype: dalegrantrobyn@outlook.com